# Sending cookies with Diffbot

Tags: diffbot

Diffbot [docs](http://support.diffbot.com/crawlbot/how-do-i-set-custom-headers-in-api-calls-or-while-crawling/) suggest that to set custom headers, including `Cookies`,I simply add the `X-Forward` prefix to the header.

For example I do the following

```
cookie='SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=CNY'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36' 
headers = {'X-Forward-User-Agent': user_agent,'X-Forward-Cookie': cookie}
```

I then make the request with my client to the URL https://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-ace-17-1-mens-fg-football-boots-203193?colcode=20319312, and I can see in Wireshark that the client correctly passed the `X-Forward` headers:

[image]

However the target site responds in USD still, not CNY.

This is contrast to a simple cURL:

```
curl 'https://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-ace-17-1-mens-fg-football-boots-203193?colcode=20319312' -H 'Cookie: SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=CNY'  --compressed | grep -A 5 pdpPrice
```

which shows the price in accord with the "SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency" as it should.

However, I finally tested using diffbot to make a request to https://webhook.site, which records any requests along with headers made to a special address it provides you.

[image]

clearly Diffbot did indeed forward my headers, so it's baffling why it would not get the right currency, when cURL does.

Comment: Diffbot uses servers in the USA, so it's possible that your IP is playing a major factor and that's why you're getting defaulted to CNY, not the header itself. Does the site return USA or CNY when trying with curl without a header?

Comment: My IP is UK. If I cURL without a header  I get GBP. If I diffbot without a header I get USD. For me, cURL with the single, `SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency` suffices to change the currency as desired, but as the answer below suggests I need 2 cookies to have diffbot change the currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce with your curl, does not work that way either. To make it work with both approaches you need to add another cookie value because of a redirect on their end. The full header is:

```
ChosenSite=www; SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=CNY;
```

Comment: Strange that you don't reproduce the cURL, I just tried again and it works fine for me to change between currencies like that with the single currency. Nevertheless, adding the extra cookie, `ChosenSite` does indeed stop the redirect with diffbot and gives me the desired response. Thanks!